# Usar window.print en Google Chrome no imprime texto

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, impresión

Estoy intentando generar la funcionalidad de impresión de cierta información "solo texto" usando la función "window.print".

Tanto en Microsoft Edge como en Internet Explorer *(IE9 y versiones superiores)* la impresión de un texto seleccionado funciona.

Sin embargo, en Google Chrome, "a pesar de que la vista previa muestra el texto a imprimir", al enviarlo a la impresora, ésta solo muestra la hoja vacía.

Para el requerimiento, estamos usando un impresora térmica *"no usa tinta"* y solo necesitamos imprimir texto.

---

El siguiente código es solo una muestra de cómo estamos construyendo "en una nueva página" la información a imprimir; pero, como he mencionado, en Google Chrome no imprime nada.

```
/* Imprimir el ejemplo. */
function printThisDocument() {
    try {           
        var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=600,width=1000');
        mywindow.document.write('<html moznomarginboxes mozdisallowselectionprint><head><title>Sticker #1</title>');
        mywindow.document.write('</head><body>');
        mywindow.document.write(document.getElementById('divOculto').innerHTML.trim());
        mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
        mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
        mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10
        setTimeout(function(){ mywindow.print(); mywindow.close(); }, 500);
    } catch (ex) {
        alert('Hubo un error al imprimir. Intente de nuevo.');
        console.log(ex);
    }
}
```

He intentado al seleccionar "en la vista previa" distintos tamaños de papel, pero solo con el tamaño "Carta" la impresión se genera; en este caso, me refiero a que la impresora "se ejecuta", pero no imprime texto. Al seleccionar otros tamaños, la impresora no usa papel ni nada, no se activa.

Lo mismo sucede si selecciono cualquier texto de cualquier página, es decir, selecciono un texto y con clic derecho selecciono la opción "Imprimir".

Leí que la imagen previa de [la impresión en Google Chrome es eso, una imagen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11530764/4092887), y como la impresora térmica no imprime imágenes, entonces no imprime nada.

¿Cuál puede ser la causa de que en Google Chrome no se pueda imprimir texto?

La respuesta aceptada también puede ser aquella que describa alternativas funcionales para la **impresión de texto plano desde el navegador**.

Comment: [Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36570689) hay una pregunta similar. Desgraciadamente, en la respuesta aceptada, se indica que **no funciona con Chrome**, y nos remiten a un [hilo sobre Chrome](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/GYf6iI42Ug4) al respecto.

Comment: @Trauma, lo gracioso es que había votado a la respuesta aceptada, pero no había leído la pregunta del todo "que es básicamente lo que intento lograr". ¿Conoces de applets de casualidad?

Comment: He estado investigando por otra via ... guardar un archivo en la impresora. [Aquí](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2230746) hacen algo parecido, pero sobre una impresora en red. Creo que es un camino que convendría investigar. **Muy interesante** la pregunta ;-)

Comment: Lo que te sugiere @Trauma es un buen dato,  hay una posibilidad bastante prehistórica que es hacer un `TYPE  archivo  > PRN`, dónde <archivo> podía ser un postscript para ese tipo de impresoras o un txt para las viejas impresoras de texto.  [Esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343047/how-to-implement-printing-in-web-application/13343409)  tal vez te dé alguna idea, lamentablemente solo para entornos windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terminé por implementar [QZ Tray 2.0.4](https://qz.io/) *la versión gratuita*.

Modificando el código disponible en la [página de prueba](https://demo.qz.io/) pude implementar correctamente la impresión de stickers a través del navegador<sup>1</sup>.

> **NOTA**: Si piensa utilizar este código, debe tener en cuenta que *(además
>   de instalar QZ Tray 2.0.4 y modificar el código para establecer
>   correctamente las referencias a los scripts)* la configuración debe ser
>   correcta y que la aplicación "QZ Tray 2.0.4" se encuentre en
>   ejecución; además de contar con la impresora de su preferencia
>   establecida como **impresora predetermianda**; así como permitir que QZ Tray se comunique con el localhost asignado.

El siguiente código lo he adaptado de la página de prueba, pero hay mas información en la página oficial *según el tipo de impresión a generar*:

```
<!-- Scripts requeridos -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/dependencies/rsvp-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/dependencies/sha-256.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/qz-tray.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    /// Uso esta función en el evento "onclick" de un botón.
    function printStuff() {

        // Crea una conexión a la impresora predefinida "según configuración del equipo del usuario".
        var config = getUpdatedConfig();

        // Valores de prueba.
        var data = ['Raw Data\n', 'More Raw Data\n', 'Even More Raw Data\n'];

        // Imprimir.
        qz.print(config, data).catch(function(e) { console.error(e); });
    }

    /// Authentication setup ///
    qz.security.setCertificatePromise(function(resolve, reject) {
        //Preferred method - from server
        //$.ajax("assets/signing/digital-certificate.txt").then(resolve, reject);

        //Alternate method 1 - anonymous
        //resolve();

        //Alternate method 2 - direct
        resolve("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" +
                "MIIFAzCCAuugAwIBAgICEAIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwgZgxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVT\n" +
                "MQswCQYDVQQIDAJOWTEbMBkGA1UECgwSUVogSW5kdXN0cmllcywgTExDMRswGQYD\n" +
                "VQQLDBJRWiBJbmR1c3RyaWVzLCBMTEMxGTAXBgNVBAMMEHF6aW5kdXN0cmllcy5j\n" +
                "b20xJzAlBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWGHN1cHBvcnRAcXppbmR1c3RyaWVzLmNvbTAeFw0x\n" +
                "NTAzMTkwMjM4NDVaFw0yNTAzMTkwMjM4NDVaMHMxCzAJBgNVBAYTAkFBMRMwEQYD\n" +
                "VQQIDApTb21lIFN0YXRlMQ0wCwYDVQQKDAREZW1vMQ0wCwYDVQQLDAREZW1vMRIw\n" +
                "EAYDVQQDDAlsb2NhbGhvc3QxHTAbBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWDnJvb3RAbG9jYWxob3N0\n" +
                "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAtFzbBDRTDHHmlSVQLqjY\n" +
                "aoGax7ql3XgRGdhZlNEJPZDs5482ty34J4sI2ZK2yC8YkZ/x+WCSveUgDQIVJ8oK\n" +
                "D4jtAPxqHnfSr9RAbvB1GQoiYLxhfxEp/+zfB9dBKDTRZR2nJm/mMsavY2DnSzLp\n" +
                "t7PJOjt3BdtISRtGMRsWmRHRfy882msBxsYug22odnT1OdaJQ54bWJT5iJnceBV2\n" +
                "1oOqWSg5hU1MupZRxxHbzI61EpTLlxXJQ7YNSwwiDzjaxGrufxc4eZnzGQ1A8h1u\n" +
                "jTaG84S1MWvG7BfcPLW+sya+PkrQWMOCIgXrQnAsUgqQrgxQ8Ocq3G4X9UvBy5VR\n" +
                "CwIDAQABo3sweTAJBgNVHRMEAjAAMCwGCWCGSAGG+EIBDQQfFh1PcGVuU1NMIEdl\n" +
                "bmVyYXRlZCBDZXJ0aWZpY2F0ZTAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUpG420UhvfwAFMr+8vf3pJunQ\n" +
                "gH4wHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUkKZQt4TUuepf8gWEE3hF6Kl1VFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEF\n" +
                "BQADggIBAFXr6G1g7yYVHg6uGfh1nK2jhpKBAOA+OtZQLNHYlBgoAuRRNWdE9/v4\n" +
                "J/3Jeid2DAyihm2j92qsQJXkyxBgdTLG+ncILlRElXvG7IrOh3tq/TttdzLcMjaR\n" +
                "8w/AkVDLNL0z35shNXih2F9JlbNRGqbVhC7qZl+V1BITfx6mGc4ayke7C9Hm57X0\n" +
                "ak/NerAC/QXNs/bF17b+zsUt2ja5NVS8dDSC4JAkM1dD64Y26leYbPybB+FgOxFu\n" +
                "wou9gFxzwbdGLCGboi0lNLjEysHJBi90KjPUETbzMmoilHNJXw7egIo8yS5eq8RH\n" +
                "i2lS0GsQjYFMvplNVMATDXUPm9MKpCbZ7IlJ5eekhWqvErddcHbzCuUBkDZ7wX/j\n" +
                "unk/3DyXdTsSGuZk3/fLEsc4/YTujpAjVXiA1LCooQJ7SmNOpUa66TPz9O7Ufkng\n" +
                "+CoTSACmnlHdP7U9WLr5TYnmL9eoHwtb0hwENe1oFC5zClJoSX/7DRexSJfB7YBf\n" +
                "vn6JA2xy4C6PqximyCPisErNp85GUcZfo33Np1aywFv9H+a83rSUcV6kpE/jAZio\n" +
                "5qLpgIOisArj1HTM6goDWzKhLiR/AeG3IJvgbpr9Gr7uZmfFyQzUjvkJ9cybZRd+\n" +
                "G8azmpBBotmKsbtbAU/I/LVk8saeXznshOVVpDRYtVnjZeAneso7\n" +
                "-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n" +
                "--START INTERMEDIATE CERT--\n" +
                "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" +
                "MIIFEjCCA/qgAwIBAgICEAAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwgawxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVT\n" +
                "MQswCQYDVQQIDAJOWTESMBAGA1UEBwwJQ2FuYXN0b3RhMRswGQYDVQQKDBJRWiBJ\n" +
                "bmR1c3RyaWVzLCBMTEMxGzAZBgNVBAsMElFaIEluZHVzdHJpZXMsIExMQzEZMBcG\n" +
                "A1UEAwwQcXppbmR1c3RyaWVzLmNvbTEnMCUGCSqGSIb3DQEJARYYc3VwcG9ydEBx\n" +
                "emluZHVzdHJpZXMuY29tMB4XDTE1MDMwMjAwNTAxOFoXDTM1MDMwMjAwNTAxOFow\n" +
                "gZgxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMQswCQYDVQQIDAJOWTEbMBkGA1UECgwSUVogSW5kdXN0\n" +
                "cmllcywgTExDMRswGQYDVQQLDBJRWiBJbmR1c3RyaWVzLCBMTEMxGTAXBgNVBAMM\n" +
                "EHF6aW5kdXN0cmllcy5jb20xJzAlBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWGHN1cHBvcnRAcXppbmR1\n" +
                "c3RyaWVzLmNvbTCCAiIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggIPADCCAgoCggIBANTDgNLU\n" +
                "iohl/rQoZ2bTMHVEk1mA020LYhgfWjO0+GsLlbg5SvWVFWkv4ZgffuVRXLHrwz1H\n" +
                "YpMyo+Zh8ksJF9ssJWCwQGO5ciM6dmoryyB0VZHGY1blewdMuxieXP7Kr6XD3GRM\n" +
                "GAhEwTxjUzI3ksuRunX4IcnRXKYkg5pjs4nLEhXtIZWDLiXPUsyUAEq1U1qdL1AH\n" +
                "EtdK/L3zLATnhPB6ZiM+HzNG4aAPynSA38fpeeZ4R0tINMpFThwNgGUsxYKsP9kh\n" +
                "0gxGl8YHL6ZzC7BC8FXIB/0Wteng0+XLAVto56Pyxt7BdxtNVuVNNXgkCi9tMqVX\n" +
                "xOk3oIvODDt0UoQUZ/umUuoMuOLekYUpZVk4utCqXXlB4mVfS5/zWB6nVxFX8Io1\n" +
                "9FOiDLTwZVtBmzmeikzb6o1QLp9F2TAvlf8+DIGDOo0DpPQUtOUyLPCh5hBaDGFE\n" +
                "ZhE56qPCBiQIc4T2klWX/80C5NZnd/tJNxjyUyk7bjdDzhzT10CGRAsqxAnsjvMD\n" +
                "2KcMf3oXN4PNgyfpbfq2ipxJ1u777Gpbzyf0xoKwH9FYigmqfRH2N2pEdiYawKrX\n" +
                "6pyXzGM4cvQ5X1Yxf2x/+xdTLdVaLnZgwrdqwFYmDejGAldXlYDl3jbBHVM1v+uY\n" +
                "5ItGTjk+3vLrxmvGy5XFVG+8fF/xaVfo5TW5AgMBAAGjUDBOMB0GA1UdDgQWBBSQ\n" +
                "plC3hNS56l/yBYQTeEXoqXVUXDAfBgNVHSMEGDAWgBQDRcZNwPqOqQvagw9BpW0S\n" +
                "BkOpXjAMBgNVHRMEBTADAQH/MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAA4IBAQAJIO8SiNr9jpLQ\n" +
                "eUsFUmbueoxyI5L+P5eV92ceVOJ2tAlBA13vzF1NWlpSlrMmQcVUE/K4D01qtr0k\n" +
                "gDs6LUHvj2XXLpyEogitbBgipkQpwCTJVfC9bWYBwEotC7Y8mVjjEV7uXAT71GKT\n" +
                "x8XlB9maf+BTZGgyoulA5pTYJ++7s/xX9gzSWCa+eXGcjguBtYYXaAjjAqFGRAvu\n" +
                "pz1yrDWcA6H94HeErJKUXBakS0Jm/V33JDuVXY+aZ8EQi2kV82aZbNdXll/R6iGw\n" +
                "2ur4rDErnHsiphBgZB71C5FD4cdfSONTsYxmPmyUb5T+KLUouxZ9B0Wh28ucc1Lp\n" +
                "rbO7BnjW\n" +
                "-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n");
    });

    qz.security.setSignaturePromise(function(toSign) {
        return function(resolve, reject) {
            //Preferred method - from server
            //$.ajax("/secure/url/for/sign-message?request=" + toSign).then(resolve, reject);

            //Alternate method - unsigned
            resolve();
        };
    });


    /// Connection ///
    function launchQZ() {
        if (!qz.websocket.isActive()) {
            window.location.assign("qz:launch");
            //Retry 5 times, pausing 1 second between each attempt
            startConnection({ retries: 5, delay: 1 });
        }
    }

    function startConnection(config) {
        if (!qz.websocket.isActive()) {
            qz.websocket.connect(config).then(function() {
                findDefaultPrinter(true); /* Instead of findVersion(); */
            }).catch(handleConnectionError);
        } else {
            displayAlert('An active connection with QZ already exists.');
        }
    }

    function endConnection() {
        if (qz.websocket.isActive()) {
            qz.websocket.disconnect().then(function() {
                alert('Desconectado');
            }).catch(handleConnectionError);
        } else {
            displayAlert('No active connection with QZ exists. Openinig a new one.');
            startConnection();
        }
    }

    // Recargar la página para iniciar la conexión.
    function restartConnection() {
        startConnection({ retries: 5, delay: 1 });
    }

    /// Detection ///
    function findDefaultPrinter(set) {
        qz.printers.getDefault().then(function(data) {
            displayAlert("La impresora (" + data + ") ha sido encontrada.\nAhora puede proceder a imprimir stickers.");
            if (set) { setPrinter(data); }
        }).catch(createConsoleLog);
    }

    /// Raw Printers ///
    function printEPL() {
        var config = getUpdatedConfig();

        /* Información de prueba. */
        var printData = [
            '\nN\n',
            'q609\n',
            'Q203,26\n',
            'B5,26,0,1A,3,7,152,B,"1234"\n',
            'A310,26,0,3,1,1,N,"SKU 00000 MFG 0000"\n',
            'A310,56,0,3,1,1,N,"QZ PRINT APPLET"\n',
            'A310,86,0,3,1,1,N,"TEST PRINT SUCCESSFUL"\n',
            'A310,116,0,3,1,1,N,"FROM SAMPLE.HTML"\n',
            'A310,146,0,3,1,1,N,"QZ.IO"\n',
            '\nP1,1\n'
        ];

        qz.print(config, printData).catch(createConsoleLog);
    }

    /// Page load ///
    $(document).ready(function() {
        window.readingWeight = false;       
        startConnection();      
        // ¡La conexión con la impresora se establece cuando la conexión sea exitosa!
        alert('============================================\n' +
              '              Iniciando conexión con QZ Tray software.\n' + 
              '============================================\n' +
              'Para usar la impresión de stickers, debe tener instalado el programa\n' +
              'QZ Tray 2.0.4\n\n' + 
              'QZ Tray 2.0.4 procederá a detectar la impresora predeterminada.\n\n' +
              'Acepte las solicitudes que se muestra a continuación y\n' +
              'Espere a que se muestre el nombre de la impresora detectada.');
    });

    qz.websocket.setClosedCallbacks(function(evt) {
        console.log(evt);

        if (evt.reason) {
            displayAlert("Connection closed:" + evt.reason);
        }
    });

    qz.websocket.setErrorCallbacks(handleConnectionError);

    /// Helpers ///
    function handleConnectionError(err) {
        if (err.target != undefined) {
            if (err.target.readyState >= 2) { //if CLOSING or CLOSED
                createConsoleLog("Connection to QZ Tray was closed");
            } else {
                createConsoleLog("A connection error occurred, check log for details");
                console.error(err);
            }
        } else {
            createConsoleLog(err);
        }
    }

    function createConsoleLog(err) {
        console.error(err);
        displayAlert(err);
    }

    function displayAlert(msg, css) {
        alert(msg);
    }

    /// QZ Config ///
    var cfg = null;
    function getUpdatedConfig() {
        if (cfg == null) {
            cfg = qz.configs.create(null);
        }

        updateConfig();
        return cfg
    }

    // Los parámetros estarán como "undefined" ya que no existen en mi código final.
    function updateConfig() {
        var pxlSize = null;
        var pxlMargins = $("#pxlMargins").val(); // = undefined.
        var jobName = "Impresión Sticker";

        cfg.reconfigure({
            altPrinting: $("#rawAltPrinting").prop('checked'),
            encoding: $("#rawEncoding").val(),
            endOfDoc: $("#rawEndOfDoc").val(),
            perSpool: $("#rawPerSpool").val(),
            colorType: $("#pxlColorType").val(),
            copies: 1,
            density: $("#pxlDensity").val(),
            duplex: $("#pxlDuplex").prop('checked'),
            interpolation: $("#pxlInterpolation").val(),
            jobName: jobName,
            margins: pxlMargins,
            orientation: $("#pxlOrientation").val(),
            paperThickness: $("#pxlPaperThickness").val(),
            printerTray: $("#pxlPrinterTray").val(),
            rasterize: $("#pxlRasterize").prop('checked'),
            rotation: $("#pxlRotation").val(),
            scaleContent: $("#pxlScale").prop('checked'),
            size: pxlSize,
            units: $("input[name='pxlUnits']:checked").val()
        });
    }

    function setPrinter(printer) {
        var cf = getUpdatedConfig();
        cf.setPrinter(printer);
    }

</script>
<!--FIN-->
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Pruebas en Google Chrome Versión 60.0.3112.90 (Build oficial) (64 bits).